# matching entries of a dataframe column with a list and creating a new column based on match

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I am looking for a pythonic way to handle this dataframe column and list matching problem:

Here is my dataframe:

[image]

Now, I have a list of roll_no.:

```
     roll_no_matching = [3,5]
```

I want to have a matching done between this list and column B a.k.a roll_no. and insert a new column which will have a 0 for no match and 1 for match. e.g. the resulting dataframe will look like:
[image]

I know how to match two dataframes based on any index column and possibly merge some columns from the two dataframes but, I am not sure how to create a new column. Any guidance here is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for test membership with convert mask to integers by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['Merit_list'] = df['roll No.'].isin(roll_no_matching).astype(int)
```

Or [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

```
df['Merit_list'] = df['roll No.'].isin(roll_no_matching).view('i1')
```

Or by [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Merit_list'] = np.where(df['roll No.'].isin(roll_no_matching), 1, 0)
```